# Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers and denote by $\text{mid}(a,b,c)$ the 'value in the middle'.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers and denote by mid$(a,b,c)$ the 'value in the middle'.
>
> Show that $\text{mid}(a,b,c) = \inf\{\sup\{a,b\}, \sup\{a,c\}, \sup\{b,c\}\}$.

Suppose that $a<b<c$. Then, it follows that $\inf\{b,c,c\}= b$, so it works, but I don't know how to formally prove this.

Comment: The value in the middle? The average value? Or the median?

Comment: @CalvinKhor The one of the three values which lies between the other two. So, I guess the median would be appropriate.

Comment: That's called the median

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality $a\le b\le c$ so the equation reduces to the trivial $b=\inf\{b,\,c,\,c\}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two options that you can use to prove it:

The first one is likely to be quite tedious. You consider all six possible orders that $a, b, c$ can be in, and prove the equation in each case.

The second is similar: You still consider a specific ordering of $a, b, c$ and prove the equation under that assumption. However, you don't consider every possible order. Instead, you notice that swapping any two variables in the equation doesn't change the value of either side of the equation. e.g. If you swap the values of $a$ and $b$, then the left hand side becomes
$$ \operatorname{mid}(b, a, c) = \operatorname{mid}(a, b, c) $$ and the right hand side similarly remains the same. Thus you can reorder $a, b, c$ as you please, and so it is enough to prove the equation for the specific case $a \leq b \leq c$, which you have already done.